# Preferred Way for Testing External Tools in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Fiddling with a build-system mainly based on pure Makefiles, I've come to the following macro to make it easy to test for the existence and set an internal variable of each external tool required by the build process.

```
define tool-available
    $(eval $(1) := $(shell which $(2)))
    $(if $($(1)),$(info $(2) available at $($(1))),$(error error: missing tool $(2)))
endef

$(eval $(call tool-available,DOT,dot))
$(eval $(call tool-available,RBIN,R))
$(eval $(call tool-available,FIND,find))
```

However, experience has shown that it's not common to do so inside a makefile, with third-party build-systems usually preferring external configure scripts and alternative mechanisms.

Besides the fact that the which(1) program has a limited availability along platforms, is there any strong reason for not doing so into a Makefile?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure there's any value in explicitly checking that the tool is available in the way your system is; if the program doesn't exist on your path, it's going to fail with a "command not found" error, which is pretty unambiguous, so why waste the time explicitly checking for it?

Checking for the presense of libraries, on the other-hand, I feel does add value. If a library is missing, you may get just a 'file not found', with no indication of *which* library it comes from, but even then, a clear documents on how to configure the build environment would be better; it's actually far easier to say "this is what you need to build this" than it is to try to handle all the edge cases of weirdly configured systems out there.

Note that my views are quite militant in this regard; if someone doesn't have the wit to read the README or BUILDING instructions and setup their environment appropriately, then they *probably* have no business attmpting to build it in the first place... people of a less cynical nature may want to take a softer line :)